# RxJS operator equivalent of ((observableX | async) || (observableY | async)) in template

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I have the following code in my component template

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="((facade.user.data$.isLoading | async) || (facade.product.data$.isLoading | async))"></mat-spinner>
```

I want to move this union to the component class as a single property and refer to it from the component template, like so

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="detailLoading | async"></mat-spinner>
```

However, I cannot find which RxJS union operator to use to property represent the condition in the observables

```
(facade.user.data$.isLoading | async) || (facade.product.data$.isLoading | async)
```

Which of the RxJS operators could I use to represent the above in my component class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need operator in template (pipe), you can create your own.

I think it should look something like this:

```
public detailLoading$: Observable<boolean> = this.facade.user.data$.pipe(
    combineLatestWith(this.facade.product.data$),
    map(data => data[0].isLoading || data[1].isLoading )
)
```

Comment: Inspired by your post, this worked for me

`messageBodyIsLoading = combineLatest([i.isLoading$, j.isLoading$, k.isLoading$]).pipe(map((current) => current.reduce((accu, currentr) => accu || current)))`

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could assign it to a single variable like this. With combineLatest we emit each time one of the observable emits. We emit one boolean value from each because combineLatest only emits *when all have emited at least once* (and you may skip it if you wish)

```
get var$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return combineLatest([
        facade.user.data$.isLoading.pipe(startWith(false)),
        facade.product.data$.isLoading.pipe(startWith(false))
    ]).pipe(
        // skip(1) ,
        map( ([a,b]) => a || b )
    )
}
```

In template I could do it like this

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ isLoading: (var$ | async ) } as foo">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="foo.isLoading"></mat-spinner>
</ng-container>
```